# Replace a character in window.location.hash url

Tags: javascript, php, anchor

so, I have an anchor that is getting called by replacing the space with a `-` using the php `str_replace`, now inside of the javascript hash I want to undo these changes so users will search for the words without these `-`. any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: question's too unclear and as to the tags used with hardly any supportive code

Comment: This can only work _one-way_ btw; you can create an URL with a fragment (hash) on the server fine - but fragments aren't sent back up to the server. Apache/PHP will never see `#badgers` in `/i-like.html#badgers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var href = "a-b-c";
    href = href.replace(/\-/g,"");

    console.log(href);
```

Will work and replace all "-" instead one.

You can try here
https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/MAZLREUGKE